# Question on equivalence classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I have a question on Equivalent Classes:
$A=\{1,2,3,4,5......,20\}$ , $R$ is define on $A$ as follows:

For All $x,y$ element of $A$, $xRy$ if and only if $4|(x-y)$

I have the answer $\{1,5,9,13,17\},\{2,6,10,14,18\},\{3,7,11,15,19\},\{4,8,12,16,20\}$

However the book didn't explain how it derive the answer, Can someone please explain to me. Thank you!

Comment: Two elements are related if and only if their difference is divisible by $4$. Equivalent classes represent different remainders when they are divided by $4$

Comment: @Mathmore Yes i know, But i am not to sure how to get the answer, The book didn't explain

Comment: @JaySun: Do you (a) think the book's answer is not in fact the equivalence classes, (b) are not convinced _that_ the book's answer are the equivalence classes, or (c) agree that the answer is correct but want the book to use a particular step-by-step procedure for finding it?

Comment: @user340297 Does that mean that each number in the class gets the same reminder therefore it is in a class?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Nope, I am just not too sure how does the book get the answer for this question, What are the steps that derived this solution.

Comment: @JaySun: Could you please answer my question: Is it (a) you think the answer is wrong, (b) you don't know how to recognize the answer as correct, or (c) you agree that the answer is correct but you're dissatisfied that the book did not use a mindless step-by-step procedure for _finding_ that correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $4$ different possible remainders after dividing by $4$: $0,1,2,$ and $3$.

Since these are the only possible remainders, every number has to be in the same equivalence class of one of them. So simply use the definition to check which class each number belongs in.

$$4|(4-0)\quad 4|(5-1)\quad 4|(6-2)\quad 4| (7-3)$$ and so on. This lets us classify *every integer* into one of four equivalence classes, the one containing $0$, the one containing $1$, the one containing $2$, and the one containing $3$. At some point you’ll probably notice the pattern that lets you shortcut having to check each one individually: the equivalence class of $k$ is the set of all integers that are $k$ more than a multiple of $4$. Notice that this is true even for $k$ not in $\{0,1,2,3\}$!

Now, your question isn’t interested in all integers, only those in $A$. So we throw out all the negative numbers, $0$, and everything bigger than $20$. What’s left is the four sets given by the book.

Comment: alright, I get the rationale behind it, basically it means that  they are grouped by same reminder, But what if there are cases where reminder is 0?

Comment: Then it goes in the equivalence class of $4$. It’s also true that $0$ *would be* in that equivalence class if $0$ was in $A$.

Comment: I think the argument would be clearer and the OP's comment would be answered if you used remainder $0$ from the start. No reason to exclude it _as a remainder_ just because it's not in the set.

Comment: @EthanBolker Good idea, I reworded the answer with that in mind.

Comment: @EthanBolker But for 1 and 2, both can be divide exactly by 4, but why are they in separate classes in this case? Thank you!

Comment: @JaySun you’re misreading the definition. Try rereading it.

Comment: alright, i finally get it. thank you for explaining to me. Much appreciated